# Best Linux Distro for web services (Nginx & node.js) on laptop: Compaq 6710b?

Tags: linux, laptop, web-development, nginx, node.js

I haven't used Linux in 5+ years, aside from d/l occasional system recovery CDs off DistroWatch, so I don't know the current landscape.  Related postings on this forum are several years old & may not relate to my hardware (Compaq 6710b laptop, Core2Duo Centrino).

Requirements:

- Use the Compaq 6710b laptop's WiFi out of the box
- enough frequently updated pre-made packages for web hosting & development 
  (Nginx & node.js are biggest concerns, everyone has Apache & PHP, & I'm not crazy about building from source)
- prefer be easy enough to use, but outside help available (so a small user-base distro is only OK if the community is active & a major disto's packages are compatable)
- configuration easy to transfer to outside web hosts.
- You have actually installed/used recommended disto (don't have to be expert)

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu mostly has everything you need, especially for the community and out-of-the-box support, since it's the most used distro thus has the best support for hardware.

It doesn't really matter what distro you use for updates, most are build upon debian or fedora anyways and thus have frequently fast updates. Nginx and the likes are added in these too, though in Debian you have to enable a bit or get outdated packages.

I'd still pick Ubuntu (server), for the fast updates and largely covered guides, though something as fedora (server) might do too, but that's based on if you like apt-get over yum.

Comment: Thanks XSlicer, I knew about Ubuntu, but not their server specific sub-distro.  My laptop is not on their official supported list, & only 2 HP/Compaq models listed does not make me enthused.
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/models?form.hardware_release=11.10&form.hardware_category=LAPTOP

Comment: With a bit more research, I did find some confirmations that Ubuntu does work out of box for my laptop:
http://nxadm.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/ubuntu-804-on-an-hp-compaq-6710b-laptop/



Any other distos please?  Last time I installed Linux was when Ubuntu was just announced as a new distro :D

Comment: Well, so far what I've used are Fedora and Debian derivatives, and those usually take those packages (and thus are up-to-date).
I'm not too certain about the out-of-the-box support for your wirless, since that's usually a scratchy thing.
So far what I know to be quite supported is Mint (Debian), though that is a bit heavier, Cruchbang (lightweight debian) or Fedora (fedoara). If you go beyond (like Arch) you might lose 'easy to be used'.